# How can I conform a Swift enum to `Equatable` when it has an any existential as one of its associated values?

Tags: ios, swift, existential-type

Suppose I have:

```swift
protocol MyError: Error, Equatable {
  var errorDispalyTitle: String { get }
  var errorDisplayMessage: String { get }
}

enum ContentState {
  case .loading
  case .error(any MyError)
  case .contentLoaded
}
```

If i were to implement `Equatable` in `ContentState` so I can compare during unit tests I end up with a problem because I have to compare two `any MyError` types which are boxed and might be of two different underlying types.

```swift
extension ContentState: Equatable {
  static func == (lhs: ContentState, rhs: ContentState) -> Bool {
    switch (lhs, rhs) {
    case (.loading, .loading):
      return true
    case (.contentLoaded, .contentLoaded):
      return true
    case (.error(let lhsError), .error(let rhsError)):
      // TODO: have to compare if both underlying types are match and then if they are equal in value
    default:
      return false
    }
  }
}
```

How do I do this?

I tried lifting the generic from the existential type there to the type (e.g. `ContentState<Error: MyError>`) which lets it compile when implementing equatable as it knows how to infer the type, but the problem is for whichever class uses that enum it doesnt matter which type is receiving of it, only that is any type of it, and if I don't implement the `any` existential it starts requiring the generic to be propagated up the chain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Swift 5.7, [Swift automatically “opens” an existential when you pass it as an argument of generic type.](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0352-implicit-open-existentials.md) The implicit `self` argument can be opened (in fact Swift has always opened the `self` argument), and Swift can open multiple arguments in a single invocation. So we can write an `isEqual(to:)` function that compares any `Equatable` to any other `Equatable` like this:

```
extension Equatable {
    func isEqual<B: Equatable>(to b: B) -> Bool {
        return b as? Self == self
    }
}
```

And then we can complete your `ContentState` conformance like this:

```
extension ContentState: Equatable {
  static func == (lhs: ContentState, rhs: ContentState) -> Bool {
    switch (lhs, rhs) {
    case (.loading, .loading):
      return true
    case (.contentLoaded, .contentLoaded):
      return true
    case (.error(let lhsError), .error(let rhsError)):
        return lhsError.isEqual(to: rhsError)
    default:
      return false
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write a wrapper that wraps an `Equatable`, and wrap the LHS and RHS errors before comparing.

```
// resembling a similar behaviour to AnyHashable...
class AnyEquatable: Equatable {
    let value: Any
    private let equals: (Any) -> Bool

    init<E: Equatable>(_ value: E) {
        self.value = value
        self.equals = { type(of: $0) == type(of: value) && $0 as? E == value }
    }

    static func == (lhs: AnyEquatable, rhs: AnyEquatable) -> Bool {
        lhs.equals(rhs.value)
    }
}
```

Then in your switch you can do:

```
case (.error(let lhsError), .error(let rhsError)):
  return AnyEquatable(lhsError) == AnyEquatable(rhsError)
```

Note that if `MyError` inherits from `Hashable` instead of `Equatable`, you can use the builtin [`AnyHashable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/anyhashable) instead of writing your own `AnyEquatable`.

Comment: Thanks! Why is it an `||` instead of an `&&` though?

Comment: @corujautx Interesting. I'm surprised I didn't notice that while answering that question. That said, I don't think it matters too much (?). I think in most cases `lhs.equals(rhs.value)` would agree with `rhs.equals(lhs.value)`. The `AnyHashable` even compares one direction only. This implementation *might* potentially have issues with optional types, e.g. a `Optional<T>.none` and a `Optional<Optional<T>>.none` would be considered as equal because they both unwrap to `Optional<T>.none`.

Comment: @corujautx See the edit. I have made it behave in a similar way to `AnyHashable`. Note that `AnyHashable` does not behave in the same way as regular `==`, especially with regards to optionals and inheritance. This is probably the simplest way to make an `AnyEquatable`, and probably not very good in terms of performance, which is why I still recommend using `AnyHashable`.

Comment: Impressive approach. The `type(of` check is redundant though because `$0 as? E == value` implies the check.

Comment: @vadian Actually removing that would change the behaviour, `as?` would sometimes successfully cast even when the types are different, like when dealing with optional types and inheritance. Since I'm trying to get to something similar to `AnyHashable`, I wouldn't want a `Dog` and `Animal` to be considered equal, just because `Animal.==` says they are. While trying to get a similar behaviour to `==` is also a valid approach (probably not so much in the context of unit testing?), that also has its own difficult parts to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Four unit testing, I would recommend extending your type with `Bool`'s as much as possible:

```swift
extension ContentState {
    var isLoading: Bool {
        if case .loading = self { return true }
        else { return false }
    }
    
    var isError: Bool {
        if case .error = self { return true }
        else { return false }
    }
    
    var isContentLoaded: Bool {
        if case .contentLoaded = self { return true }
        else { return false }
    }
}
```

, as I assume you're mostly interested in testing if some object properly updates its state.

This makes unit tests easier to write and read, and they better transmit the intent.

If you want to also explicitly check the error, you could make use of generics:

```swift
extension ContentState {
    func wrappedError<T: MyError>() -> T? {
        if case let .error(error as T) = self { return error }
        else { return nil }
    }
}
```

, and assert on that:

```swift
XCTAssertEqual(state.wrappedError(), TestError.error1)
```